# Error while configuring Ambient data framework in order to create smarttarget with dd4t.NET page

Tags: 2013, ambient-data-framework

I am getting the following error while trying to configure the Ambient Data Framework. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

`<JavaException>
  <Type>com/tridion/ambientdata/AmbientDataException</Type>
  <Message><![CDATA[Cannot find claim processor implementation class: com.tridion.ugc.odata.claimprocessor.AllowAnonymousPostClaimProcessor]]></Message>
  <StackTrace><![CDATA[com.tridion.ambientdata.AmbientDataException: Cannot find claim processor implementation class: com.tridion.ugc.odata.claimprocessor.AllowAnonymousPostClaimProcessor
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.claimProcessorDefinitionFromConfig(EngineFactory.java:114)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.cartridgeDefinitionFromConfig(EngineFactory.java:68)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.newEngine(EngineFactory.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.ugc.odata.claimprocessor.AllowAnonymousPostClaimProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.claimProcessorDefinitionFromConfig(EngineFactory.java:110)
    ... 2 more
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo)
   at Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.EngineFactory.NewEngine()
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.AmbientRuntime.Setup()
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)]]></StackTrace>
</JavaException>`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a UGC cartridge configured in cd_ambient_conf.xml but you do not have the JAR files that contain said cartridge (ugc_webservice.jar). Either add the JAR file or remove the cartridge from the configuration, depending on whether or not you need the cartridge to run.

Comment: No UGC cartridge is not configured in cd_ambient_conf.xml and no such jar file in my .net web application.

Comment: It's clearly trying to load that cartridge, so perhaps it has loaded a different configuration file than you think? Also keep in mind that you probably have to restart the web application when you make changes to that file, for them to take effect.

Comment: If you removed the reference to the ugc cartridge while your application was running, please restart your application. The conf files are loaded into memory. Changes to the conf files require a restart of your web application.